# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' _ Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

How should I extract text from the website? Below is the code I wrote for which attribute error displayed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get('https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/21101016504')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ISSN = soup.find(id='issn').text
print(ISSN)
```

Comment: Well, so clearly `soup.find(id='issn')` returned `None`, but you're not checking that before trying to access its `.text` property. Why do you think that `find()` should return something? Do you know why it might not be returning something?

Comment: I am new to webscraping. Can you help me find what I have done wrong

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to do. Maybe you need to follow more tutorials? This seems pretty basic.

Comment: You should copy the html response you get (page.content) and put that in an HTML file, then open it with your browser to see what page you're working with